# Convert 24-bit PNG files to 8-bit color indexed images with pypng

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, png, pypng

I'm trying to write a python script that takes in standard 24-bit pngs and converts them to 8-bit pngs for better compression. It looks like pypng can do this but I can't quite figure out how to use it. Image manipulation is a new area for me so this may seem silly. I have this currently:

```
r=png.Reader(<myfile>)
test = r.asRGBA8()
```

This gives me tuples in return (the layers of the image I believe). However I can't seem to write or save this back to an image. What am I missing? [Here's a test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Db9.png)

Comment: You can do it without writing any Python using **ImageMagick** in Terminal like this `magick input.png PNG8:output.png`

Comment: Or you can do it easily with PIL/Pillow if that is an option?

Comment: I'm using PIL for everything else but didn't see any functionality for this conversion. I know it can do RGBA to RGB but I would like to convert to 8 bits and keep opacity. How does it work?

Comment: Can you share a representative image please, so I can test.

Comment: I added a test png to the original post. Not sure if this is what you meant so let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Mmm... that shows up as a JPEG, with no transparency (obviously).

Comment: Ah, it should've been a png but you are correct, no transparency. I have updated the image to a logo with transparent background. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Original Answer**

I think this does what you ask:

```
from PIL import Image

# Load image
im = Image.open('logo.png')                                                                 

# Convert to palette mode and save
im.convert('P').save('result.png')
```

---

**Updated Answer**

I can't find a way to get PIL to make a sensible palette image as a result, but can do it a couple of other ways...

Either with `wand` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='logo.png') as img: 
    img.quantize(number_colors=256, colorspace_type='lab', treedepth=0, dither=False, measure_error=False)
    img.save(filename='result.png')
```

Or, by shelling out to **ImageMagick** at the command-line and doing:

```
magick logo.png -colors 255 png8:logo8.png      # use "convert" in place of "magick" if using v6
```

[image]

**Newest Answer**

Ok, I found a way to get PIL/Pillow to do a better job, and as expected, it makes use of `libimagequant` which is not normally built into Pillow (at least on macOS where I am). The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Load image
im = Image.open('logo.png')                                                                 

# Convert to palette mode and save. Method 3 is "libimagequant"
im.quantize(colors=256, method=3).save('result.png')
```

The steps, on macOS to build PIL/Pillow with `libimagequant` are as follows - they will differ on other platforms but you should be able to get the general idea and adapt:

```
pip uninstall pillow           # remove existing package
brew install libimagequant
brew install zlib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"
pip install --upgrade Pillow --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="--enable-imagequant" --global-option="--enable-zlib"
```

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, PIL/Pillow, libimagequant, macOS, quantise, quantize.

Comment: This works great! Only problem I'm having now is that gradients don't work well in the 8 bit "Palette" mode. Is there a workaround for this or is the best way to go just figuring out if an image has gradients beforehand somehow?

Comment: Gradients rarely work well in palette mode and normally exhibit *"banding"*... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding Maybe you can share a representative image to try some things on.

Comment: Banding is definitely what I'm seeing. Thanks for the article, I learned quite a bit! I changed the image in my initial question to a logo png with transparency and a gradient that displays the banding when put into palette mode. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as is all you've done so far. Perhaps I need to do some dithering on the image?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have another look.

Comment: And once more - which will hopefully be even better for you as you normally use Pillow.

Comment: How would I push the PIL implementation a little further? I'm attempting to write this myself instead of pay for a product I don't use enough to justify it -- this code works well but is consistently a few % behind what can be achieved with the other product. Can I change the quality level somehow? The quality flag in save() doesn't seem to have any effect with this implementation.